# Dark statusbar in TabBar controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm having this odd issue, where my status bar gets all black, only when I'm using a tab bar controller. Is there a way to fix this? I obviously want it the same color as the navigation bar.

[image]

Here's a screenshot of the navigation and tab bar controller in my storyboard.

[image]

Comment: - First : create your UIImage from the navigation bar color, with image height = navigation bar height + status bar height. And then, add to your navigation bar backgroundImage, not backgroundColor

Answer (score 4):

1. You can change the info.plist the row **View controller-based status bar appearance** and set it to `NO`
2. Then put this line of code in your `appDelegate.swift` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

   `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent`

Answer (score 2):

This problem seems to be the navigation bar not covering the background of the status bar. You should embed your view controller in navigation controller instead of adding navigation bar directly.

Comment: I have my tab bar viewcontroller embedded in a navigation controller

Comment: Do you set bar tint color of your navigation bar?

Comment: Yea, I set it like this self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 57, green: 79, blue: 116) in the tab bar controller.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem. Maybe you can include a screenshot of your storyboard or more information of how they are linked.

Comment: There is a lot of possibilities this could happened.
1) It might be you setting the navigation bar clipsToBounds

2) In case the navigation bar not covering the status bar, the color will be based on the color of your view.

Comment: I've added some of my storyboard.

Comment: ClipToBounds is not checked.

Comment: Could you show the storyboard of you trying to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of what i'm seeing your status bar seems fine since its white on a dark color

What you need to do is change your Bar Tint Color in the Navigation Controller as follows

[image]

The on change it on the attribute inspector

[image]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try adding View controller-based status bar appearance to info.plist and set the value to NO. And add this in app delegate:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

Or

Try overriding this method:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Comment: Did you set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to No in info.plist?

Comment: Yea, I did. Nothing changed.

Comment: Can you check "Debug view hierarchy" and see what is changing it's color?

Answer (score 1):

UINavigationBar has a bit of a strange behavior when it comes to the color you set on it. As other members have pointed out, you do have to set the translucent boolean to false, but this isn't all to get your bar to match the color you are trying to set. It will be close, but if you look carefully it will not be the exact color you are trying to use. In order to set the true color on UINavigationBar you need to understand what it is doing.

Let's say that I wanted to set my UINavigationBar to this cool color green.

That would be an RGB value of: R=90 | G=200 | B=95.

What UINavigationBar will do is apply it's built-in styling by giving this green a "glossy" look. The result for us is that it is taking our green RGB values and upping each by a factor of 20.

If you look close the green square above does not exactly match the one UINavigationBar is displaying with the same RGB values. This looks just slightly brighter.

To fix this, simply reduce the RBG values by 20 for the color you intend to use for the UINavigationBar's in your application.

So R=90 | G=200 | B=95 will become R=70 | G=180 | B=75.

Answer (score 1):

I think in you case you should try to change statusView background color.

The better place is setupAppearances func which called at the start of app.

```
let yourColor: UIColor = .gray
UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = yourColor
```

Comment: UIApplication has no member statusBarView.